# Session Object is returning Null

Tags: java, servlets

```
public class FirstServletClass extends HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -45872253821246793L;
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException ,IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if(request.getParameter("userName")!=null){
            session.setAttribute("UserName", request.getParameter("userName")) ;
        }
        pw.print("HI From Server <br/>");
        pw.print("Accessing Value from Response object    "+request.getParameter("userName")+"<br/>");
        pw.print("Accessing Value from Session object    "+(String)session.getAttribute("userName")+"<br/>");

        System.out.println("Get Method Called");
    }


}
```

When hitting url "http://localhost:8080/Servlets/niteshServlet?userName=nitesh" below output is coming:

> HI From Server
>
> Accessing Value from Response object nitesh
>
> Accessing Value from Session object null

Please suggest, Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting attribute `UserName` but retrieving attribute `userName`. It is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

While setting userName in the session, you are using attribute name as `UserName`, but you are trying to access it using `userName`. Use camel case attribute name in both the cases.

Change code to:

```
session.setAttribute("userName", request.getParameter("userName"));
```

Comment: Thanks Jeevan. Got my mistake